# Which used Mac Mini for IOS development

Tags: ios

I need to develop iOS application for iPhone 6 and Apple watch. For this I am considering to buy  a used Mac Mini  2.5Ghz | i5 | 4GB | 500GB -- MD387LL/A (October, 2012)

1. Will I be able to develop iOS and Apple watch apps on latest iOS revision on this mac mini ?
2. Can this mac mini be upgraded to latest OSX upgrade ?

Thanks in advance.
SJ

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone is going to flag you for an inappropriate question, but I use a 2012 mini and it works great for iOS development. I would add more memory and an SSD when you have the means.

Comment: ok thanks. curious , why would anyone post this message as inappropriate ?

Answer (score 1):

- [OS X El Capitan will work with Mac Mini 2009 or newer and the extra features will work with Mac Mini 2012 or newer.](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP728?locale=en_US)
- [Yes, XCode 7, Apple's IDE for developing everything OS X / iOS related, will run on OS X El Capitan.](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Basically, you are good to go. [Install extra memory if possible to speed up build / test times.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Late+2012+RAM+Replacement/11726)

Answer (score 1):

Yes your Mac mini is good for app development and is also upgradable to next OSX version. For fast system processing you need to install 8GB RAM in your system.