# mac mini 4gb for developing IOS mobile apps ( like social networking and etc.. )

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I am willing to buy a mac mini for developing IOS apps for iphones ( social networking type ) and these are my mac mini information

1.4 GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor

4GB memory

500GB hard drive

Intel HD Graphics 5000

OS X Yosemite

please I would like to know if this is good or not and whether I can use it for developing or not and can I use latest xcode on it ?

NOTE :: I am willing mac mini due to budget problems and I will only open xcode on it ( I will not open allot of programs together )

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which used Mac Mini for IOS development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449697/which-used-mac-mini-for-ios-development)

Comment: Everything is OK, but in future - buy more `RAM` - 8 GB or even 16 GB is much better.

Comment: yes it is planed too but after buying it with sometime .. but if this will make it work till i upgrade then ok

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan and please some people told me that mac mini cant be upgraded anymore as it is locked or something is that true ?

Comment: No, you can do it, - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATA6zKyw9ec

Comment: if this means that any model can be opened then i can upgrade easily .. thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be okay for Xcode and related stuff, but the processor speed is rather low, and the regular hard drive is slow by today's standards. Also, 4GB RAM is still okay for running Yosemity or Mavericks, but the OS will need to swap or compress memory very soon. You'll probably be able to use this system for what you want, but don't expect it to be too fast, especially the HDD is considered a bottleneck.

It is very likely that you'll be able to improve the speed of that computer a lot by upgrading the HDD to an SSD and the 4GB of RAM to 8GB. Both can be done by any computer store or even by yourself.